# else if condition fails when testing against more then two arguments from an array

Tags: c++

I am trying to output an error message by checking if entered parameters by the user match parameters in an array.

But when i want to test more than 2 arguments, the ``èlse if``` interpretes every passed arguments as matching the condition for the error message, even if arguments don't match the condition.

Thx in advance, here is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
.
.
.
   uint16_t sln [6] = { 1632, 2480, 2900, 3408, 4624, 6624 };
   uint8_t slt [6] = { 33, 45, 57, 67, 95, 115 };
   char* endptr1;
   char* endptr2;
   char* endptr3;
   long int narg = strtol(argv[1], &endptr1, 10);
   long int targ = strtol(argv[2], &endptr2, 10);
   long int i = strtol(argv[3], &endptr3, 10);
   if (endptr1 == argv[1]) {
     std::cerr << "ERROR invalid number: " << argv[1] << '\n';
     return -1;
   } else if ( (narg != sln[0]) || (targ != slt[0]) || (narg != sln[1]) || (targ != slt[1]) /* and so on..........*/ ) {
     std::cerr << "ERROR not permittet arguments chosen: " << argv[1] << "; " << argv[2] <<'\n';
     std::cerr << "first argument must be the n-parameter for mc-eliece, second argument must be the t-parameter for mc-eliece: " <<'\n';
     std::cerr << "third argument must be selection of RNG type: 1 = TSS_API_RNG  2 = DUMMY_RNG" << '\n';
     std::cerr << "allowed parameter combinations for parameter n, parameter t are:" << '\n';
     std::cerr << "SL=80 n=1632 t=33" << '\n';
     std::cerr << "SL=107 n=2480 t=45" << '\n';
     std::cerr << "SL=128 n=2960 t=57" << '\n';
     std::cerr << "SL=147 n=3408 t=67" << '\n';
     std::cerr << "SL=191 n=4624 t=95" << '\n';
     std::cerr << "SL=256 n=6624 t=115" << '\n';
     return -2;

   return 0;
}
```

And here is the output:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/projects/RNG_final $ ./mc_eliece 1632 33 1
ERROR not permittet arguments chosen: 1632; 33
first argument must be the n-parameter for mc-eliece, second argument must be the t-parameter for mc-eliece:
third argument must be selection of RNG type: 1 = TSS_API_RNG  2 = DUMMY_RNG
allowed parameter combinations for parameter n, parameter t are:
SL=80 n=1632 t=33
SL=107 n=2480 t=45
SL=128 n=2960 t=57
SL=147 n=3408 t=67
SL=191 n=4624 t=95
SL=256 n=6624 t=115
```

I must be a problem with the usage of the OR operator i guess.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. To ask a question here, please provide a minimal reproducible example. Many of us simply won't read a question like this if it's too unnecessarily long (like me). Also, please don't include the line numbers in your code, this makes it impossible to copy-paste without annoying editing.

Comment: That condition will always evaluate to true since `(a != b) || (a != c)` is always true when `b != c`, and you are checking `(narg != sln[0]) || (narg != sln[1])`.

Comment: @dxiv ok thx, makes sense.